Function definition estimation
Good day, not a mathematician here!
I have been trying to approximate a certain function given some known and unknown values.
Let $ M $ be a variable such that $M$ ranges from 1 to 106 with a step size of 1.
Let $D$ be a variable such that $D$ ranges from 2 to 64 with a step size of 0.125,
$$
D \in \{ 2, 2.125, 2.25, 2.375, \ldots, 63.875, 64 \}.
$$
Let $ O$ be a variable such that $O$ ranges from 2 to 128 with a step size of 0.125,
$$
O \in \{ 2, 2.125, 2.25, 2.375, \ldots, 127.875, 128 \}.
$$
Let $B$ be a variable such that
$$
B \in \{ 1, 2, 4, 8 \}.
$$
Let $F_0$ (equal to 12), $ L_0$ (equal to 4.69), $L_1 $ (equal to 800) be constants and $ F_1 $ be a real number such that
$$
1 \leq F_1 \leq 20, \quad F_1 \in \mathbb{R}^+.
$$
Let us now suppose some constraints and relations to further constrain the problem:
$$
L_0 \leq \frac{F_0 \cdot M}{D \cdot O} \leq L_1
$$
$$
600 \leq F_0 \cdot M \leq 1200
$$
$ F_1 $ has the following equation with all the other variables
$$
F_1 = \frac{F_0 \cdot M}{D \cdot O \cdot B}
$$
It is easy to see that many possible combinations of ranges of those values can satisfy the following equations. And also that the theoretical ranges can be constrained a bit given that the values of $ F_0 $ and $ F_1 $ have been constrained
What I would like to find out is how can one be able to get the 4 unknown values $( M, D, O, B )$ from the constant $ F_0 $ and the variable $ F_1$.
How does one proceed to resolve such an equation? Is there at least a way to approximate the values?
Thanks in advance!

So to put it simply: given, say, $F_1$, can we recover all other variables?

Yes exactly! Or in other words one of the possible combinations that yeilds a values close to $F_1$  (close enough being +- 0.001)

My issue is that you want to recover four variables from just one. There may be a numerical search that can be done, but it may be slow.
